# Why does this lowest common denominator function return undefined for higher numerical inputs

Tags: javascript, arrays

For each subarray, index[0] is the numerator and index[1] is the denominator. I am trying to create a function that returns the lowest common denominator of all "fractions" in the subarrays. My code is working for lower numbers but at some point stops working and returns undefined.

```
const convertFrac = (lst) => {
    let final = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < lst.length; i++) {
       final.push(lst[i][1]);
    }
    let count = 1;
    for (let j = 0; j < final.length; j++) {
        count *= final[j];
    }
    for (let k = 1; k <= count; k++) {
        function multiplier(currentValue) {
            return k % currentValue === 0;
          }
        if (final.every(multiplier)) {
            return k;
        }
        else {
            return count;
        }
    }

}
console.log(convertFrac([ [3, 318493911], [1, 611139393] ]));
```

Comment: As C# compiler would say: _"not all code branches return a value"_

Comment: try `k <= count` in your for loop.

Comment: What do you mean with "least"? Do you mean the rarest (e.g. the factor shared by the fewest number of fractions) or the lowest (e.g. the value closest to zero on the number line)?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans the lowest

Comment: Could you update your post to make that clear to others?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir except that in JS, of course, they do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern JS has a lot of built-in functionality to streamline this code. If we rewrite it a little, it might become easier to spot where things go wrong. And let's also name those functions/variables in a way that match what we actually use them for because being able to understand your own code is 99% of future work:

```
// There is no "this" preservation necessary here, so just write a function.
function findLCD(fractions) {

  // push all denominators to separate array
  let denominators = fractions.map(i => i[1]);

  // obtain a common multiple by multiplying all denominators
  let denominatorProduct = denominators.reduce((tally, value) => tally * value, 1);

  // loop over all integers up to the denominator product,
  // and see if any of those work as LCD, starting at 2 (not 1!)
  for (let k = 2; k < denominatorProduct; k++) {
    if (denominators.every(value => k % value === 0)) return k;
  }
}
```

We can now do some much easier debugging because there's not a lot of code to fiddle with. Clearly that `denominators.every()` is not doing the right thing, so: some console logs should reveal, really quickly, where things are going wrong. In fact, there are only so many things that *can* be wrong:

1. Are we starting at the right `k`?
2. Does `k` run to a high enough number?
3. Is the increment for `k` wrong?
4. Is the arrow function using the wrong maths?

And that's basically it.

1. We can't really start "too early" to find a result, although starting at 1 is guaranteed to waste some time because 1 is, by definition, never an LCD.
2. hmmmmmmm...
3. It's super naive (maths tells us there are loads of `k` values that cannot possibly yield a result, but we're going to be checking them anyway) but incrementing by 1 mean we skip nothing, which means if there is an LCD, we should find it.
4. No, that's exactly what it should be.

Clearly, 2 is the problem here, and we can also see that the code comment isn't right either, so a fix involves changing both the code, and the documentation:

```
...
  ...

  // loop over all integers up to and including the denominator product,
  // and see if any of those work as LCD, starting at 2 (not 1!)
  for (let k = 2; k <= denominatorProduct; k++) {
    if (denominators.every(value => k % value === 0)) return k;
  }
}
```

which now yields:

```
console.log(findLCD([ [3, 30], [1, 6] ])); // 30
console.log(findLCD([ [3, 31], [1, 6] ])); // undefined: let's do more debugging!
console.log(findLCD([ [3, 38], [1, 6] ])); // 114
console.log(findLCD([ [3, 3111], [1, 6111] ])); // 6337107
```

Comment: I appreciate your help Mike. Regarding your second point, why wouldn't k run to a high enough number if the maximum number it runs to is equal to the multiple of all denominator inputs?

Comment: Why indeed? But let us look at the code. Does your code, which says `k < multiple`, which translates to "the maximum number it runs to is _one below the multiple of all denominator inputs_" do what you say it should be doing when you say "the maximum number it runs to _is equal to the multiple of all denominator inputs_"?

Comment: That part I understand. When I change it to `k <= multiple` it still returns undefined for denominator examples like 3111 and 6111 and many combinations of numbers.

Comment: I just copy-pasted this code (with the `<=` change added) into my console and ran it, and it does indeed get 31-6 wrong, so: let's keep going: we have working code, where would you put `console.log` instructions to find out what's going wrong? Me, I'd add a `if (k===186) { console.log(k, value, k%value); }` inside that `every()` arrow function, to see what happens during the iteration where we _know_ it should work, but for some reason it's not working.

Comment: I figured it out by returning count if the `LCD === count` thanks @Mike